# How to implement a custom command In Cypress test

Tags: cypress, cucumberjs

I wrote a custom command to get authentication token from the window like below

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getToken", AUTH => {
 return cy.window().then(window => window.localStorage.getItem(AUTH));
});
```

```
const authToken = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("AUTH")); 

authToken = returned the authtoken. I want to know how to make`enter code here` this as 
function/custom command so that the other t`enter code here`est could use this.
```

Comment: I want to use the authtoken in the below place in the tests```headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken.token}`,
          },```

Comment: But you want to send request with this token from cypress or application?

Comment: From Cypress tests

Comment: Of course, but are you using `cy.request(url)` in your test?

Comment: yes like this ```cy.request({
          method: "POST",
          url: `${Cypress.env("apiBaseUrl")}/versions`,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken.token}`,
          },
        ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```js
describe('', () => {
  let tokens = {};

  it('', () => {
    cy
      .getToken('AUTH', ({ token }) => {
        Object.assign(tokens, { auth: token });
      })
      .request({
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", Authorization: `Bearer ${tokens.auth}`, }
      })

  });
});
```

Also you have to change little bit `getToken` command:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getToken", (AUTH, cb) => {
 return cy.window().then(window => cb(window.localStorage.getItem(AUTH)));
});
```

Comment: Hi, I get TypeError: cb is not a function. Could I know what this cb does please

Comment: cb stands for callback, I forgot first argument `AUTH` try now I edited answer

Comment: I get 401 error for the request because   "Authorization": "Bearer undefined",

Comment: hmmmm, try add `console.log(token)` before object.assign

Comment: console.log returned `{"token":"eyJraWQiOiJXYVwvQXNBUkJQN25iWGw3V2I4NEo1TVptQWVLTVAxdWl0ZWdIYXY2S004az0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyNTgzOGUzMy0xMWQ2LTRjOGYtOWYzZC05ZGQ0YjYxZjgwNTAiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZm,"accountName": "UK","accountId":19645,"singleAccount":true}

Comment: I think `request` was called before `assign`. I added return to command, and destructor to callback. Pls try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208640/discussion-between-tanya-and-przemyslaw-jan-beigert).

Comment: Cypress.Commands.add("getToken", (AUTH, cb) => { the AUTH variable is not actually used in the command but when i remove I get TypeError: cb is not a function
Please let know why would we use the argument AUTH if we never used its value